# Gitlab pipeline trigger gives 404 when pasting webhook URL in the browser

Tags: api, gitlab, pipeline, webhooks

I've created a pipeline trigger in Gitlab as the documentation said, but when I open it I get a   "error": "404 Not Found".

Webhook URL: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/xxxx/ref/xxxx/trigger/pipeline?token=xxxx

xxxx is being replaced by the values I have. Tried different things, setting the project to public. Enabling/disabling Limit CI_JOB_TOKEN acces.

I'm a bit lost right now.

Answer (score 0):

As examples show you need to use http `POST` method

```sh
curl -X POST $WEBHOOK_URL
```

If you are pasting the URL directly to your browser it will use http `GET` and result in 404 error.

Comment: Sure, you can accept the answer if this solves your problem :)

Comment: This is not entirely correct, the documentation clearly describes the possibility to trigger a pipeline either through curl or  by a webhook. The example given is a simple URL which includes the token as GET parameter. Still, it does not work using the webhook, but it does using the curl based approach.

Comment: `it does not work using the webhook` what do you mean by that? You configured some app to send webhook to your Gitlab and the pipeline was not triggered?
After quick googling as a rule of thumb most webhooks are performed using HTTP `POST`. Actually I never met with HTTP `GET` in webhooks, could you give an example which app does it in such way?

Answer (score 0):

The feature that you are referencing in the question might not be working due to a GitLab bug that was introduced in 12.0.0. Please see the issue here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/30486